# Order By Oracle Function In JPA Criteria Builder

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, eclipselink

I have the following SQL

```
SELECT ID,LASTTIMEEXECUTEDDATE as d FROM STATISTICSDATE ORDER BY LASTTIMEEXECUTEDDATE
```

which using CriteriaBuilder works just fine:

```
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<StatisticsDate> cq = cb.createQuery(StatisticsDate.class);
    Root<StatisticsDate> rootEntry = cq.from(StatisticsDate.class);        
    CriteriaQuery<StatisticsDate> all = cq.select(rootEntry).orderBy(cb.desc(
    rootEntry.get("lastTimeExecutedDate")));
    TypedQuery<StatisticsDate> allQuery = em.createQuery(all);
```

However now i need to get more accurate results using this:

```
SELECT ID,LASTTIMEEXECUTEDDATE as d FROM STATISTICSDATE ORDER BY 
to_timestamp(LASTTIMEEXECUTEDDATE, 'DD.MM.YYYY:HH24:MI:SS')  desc;
```

I can do this via native sql BUT i would like to know if it is possible to use it via CriteriaBuilder.

What troubles me is `to_timestamp(LASTTIMEEXECUTEDDATE, 'DD.MM.YYYY:HH24:MI:SS')`

Thanks

Comment: Which type is `lastTimeExecutedDate`?

Comment: Unfortunately string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<StatisticsDate> cq = cb.createQuery(StatisticsDate.class);
Root<StatisticsDate> rootEntry = cq.from(StatisticsDate.class);
CriteriaQuery<StatisticsDate> all = cq.select(rootEntry).orderBy(cb.desc(
    cb.function(
        "to_timestamp", Timestamp.class,
        rootEntry.get("lastTimeExecutedDate"),
        cb.literal("DD.MM.YYYY:HH24:MI:SS")
    )
));

TypedQuery<StatisticsDate> allQuery = em.createQuery(all);
```

Comment: I did it via native query, running your solution gave me a strange error:Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The attribute [LASTTIMEEXECUTEDDA
TE] from the managed type [EntityTypeImpl@208718431:StatisticsDate [ javaType: c
lass sep.tools.StatisticsDate descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(sep.tools.Statist
icsDate --> [DatabaseTable(STATISTICSDATE)]), mappings: 2]] is not present.
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metamodel.ManagedTypeImpl.getAtt
ribute(ManagedTypeImpl.java:147)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.querydef.FromImpl.get(FromImpl.j
ava:312)

Comment: You need to substitute the column name LASTEXECUTEDDATE with the associated property name. Check the updated Criteria query.

Comment: The cb.function() method doesn't seem to work in the .orderBy() for me for custom functions. it works fine for standard functions. my custom function gets replaced with 'least' function at runtime..